# function sum(boolean) does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Switching from sqlite to Postgres and I get this error in django:

> function sum(boolean) does not exist
> LINE 1: ..."."longitude", "pins_pin"."category_id", COALESCE(SUM("pins_...
>
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

`viewsets.py`:

```
class PinViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = pin.objects.annotate(
        num_of_upvotes=Coalesce(Sum('upvoters__upvote'), Value(0))
    )
    ...
```

`models.py`:

```
class Pin(models.Model):
    ....

class UpvoteStory(models.Model):
    pin = models.ForeignKey("pin", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='upvoters')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    upvote = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

`num_of_upvotes` should count the positive upvotes for each pin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to do this with [`Sum`, `Case`, `When`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) to count every time `upvoters__upvote` is `True`

```
pin.objects.annotate(
    num_of_upvotes=Sum(Case(
        When(upvoters__upvote=True, then=1),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    ))
)
```

Comment: do i need to import something for `IntegerField()`

Comment: from django.db.models import IntegerField

Comment: if a new user tries to upvote a pin, it doesnt get updated

Comment: The annotation worked though? When you say it doesn't get updated, does a new entry with `upvote=True` get inserted into the DB?

Comment: 1. yea the error goes away.
2. yea I am trying to get count the upvotes for each pin

Comment: Was the count correct the first time you requested the API?

Comment: oh it works. tho when a pin is created, the value goes to null

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot to include a default value. Added it now

Comment: any reason why Coalesce would not work with postgres?

Comment: Coalesce __does__ work with postgres. The error you had was trying to use "SUM" on a boolean column, postgres does not treat booleans as integers

Answer (score 0):

Postgres does not support `SUM`ing boolean fields.  You can use [`Cast`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#cast)  to cast it to an integer:

```
pin.objects.annotate(
    num_of_upvotes=Sum(Cast(upvoters__upvote, output_field=IntegerField())),
)
```